# Как произвести запись/чтение textArea js?

Tags: javascript

Не походит не одна функция?Читать могу а записать не могу:
 `function setText0() {` !!! <-------------на вот этой строке.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <html>
    <script>
function getText0() {
  str1 = document.getElementById('T1'); 
  alert(str1.value + "");
 
}
function setText0() {     
//Не могу понять что сюда вставить, чтобы все рабоатало пробовал разные функции.
} 


setText0();
</script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="T1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="getText0()" />

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script>
  function getText0() {
    return document.getElementById('T1').value;
  }

  function setText0(value) {
    document.getElementById('T1').value = value;
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    setText0("The walrus and the carpenter ...");
  });
</script>

<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="T1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="console.log(getText0())" />
```

Comment: Игорь, Вы настоящий профессионал своего дела. Мне очень приятно было наблюдать за Вашими работами и проводить ночи бок о бок. Всего Вам наилучшего.

Comment: Рекомендую!!!Hello World!!Блестящая работа! А почему нельзя вызвать функцию в том же скрипте (<script>), в том же не получается.Браво!!!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Можно, но ее вызов тогда надо завернуть в `window.onload`, так как в момент выполнения кода в первом скриптовом блоке элемента `textarea` еще нет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, правильно ли я считываю textArea?А? что то ничего не выходит!!!

Comment: @ArthurAlunts В ответe код работает?

Comment: @Igor  @Denis640Kb   Вот так не работает: `setText0(getText0());` пробовал ставить return все равно не работает! Увы.

Comment: @ArthurAlunts Что должно произойте в результате вызова `setText0(getText0());`?

Comment: вроде бы разобрался просто попробую поэкспериментировать, позже отпишусь ок ничего что я разговариваю с вами по английски ок?

Comment: @Igor localStorage["1"]=(getText0()); попробовал не получилось, где опубликовать мой полный код?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts В вопросе, лучше - в новом.

Comment: bravo blesk ! [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086959/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-textarea-%d0%b8-localstorge]